# how to combine multiple tables across multiple excel files and sheets in Python/VBA to form a consolidated table

Tags: python, vba, excel

Is it possible to combine multiple tables across multiple excel files and sheets in Python/VBA to form a consolidated table? I need to create a pivot table on this consolidated table for further analysis.

This is for analysis of monthly status reported by a team. Suppose that the team reports their status as a weekly excel file. So as the input I have 4 excel files (one excel file per week of the month), each excel file has 2 sheets ( one for each product that the team is working on) and each sheet has 2 tables ( 1 table for the development team and one table for the testing team)

How do I parse each of these excel files and combine all the T1 tables, T2 tables, T3 tables and T4 tables?

I have accomplished this manually currently in Excel 2016 by the following steps:
1. Open a new excel file
2. Load all the tables(from the 4 excel files) into this file by "Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From Workbook -> Select the file that you want(browse dialog box) -> Select all the tables (Navigator dialog box ) -> Click on Load button"
3. Combine tables by "Data -> Get Data -> Combine Queries -> Append"

I want to accomplish this via Python/VBA but I am not able to find any source online where I can read excel tables into memory. Pandas read_excel() method, reads the entire excel sheet into a data frame and that doesn't really solve my purpose. I couldn't find anything in the xlrd, XlsxWriter modules either.

Please help.

Comment: Is using a `python` a condition to this question?

Comment: Look into powerquery. That will do it. Set the query to process files from a source folder and hey presto. Should be able to do it all in memory.

Comment: Yes. If the structure of each file is the same, you can try `ADODB` using sql query.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Besides the solutions provided before, if you know how to do it manually, record the macro. That's the first step. Start coding. Do not ask for a Complete full free code to do that here.

Comment: @AntiDrondert - wanted to automate this task and hence was considering python

Comment: @QHarr thanks for the lead! :) Do you mean writing a query to do this entire task in the Excel Query Editor?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes though you abstract it enough that it will apply to any files that you place in the folder. Assume there is way to distinguish which tables come from which files? The pain is setting it up for the first time successfully. Do the file format change alot? In which case, might be easier to use a different solution.

Comment: Also, look into ADOX.Catalog for grabbing the tables if you decide to go down the ADOB route.

Comment: @QHarr yes, the idea is to keep it as generic as possible. There are four distinct tables and these occur in all the excel files (and their sheets within ). The file format is .xlsm and that's not going to change. Yes, it's going to be a task to test it out for the first time as I have no experience on powerquery but I'm hoping that it's doable!

Comment: I would highly recommend the ExcelIsFun videos covering PowerQuery. The instructor is amazing and you learn tons of other tidbits at the same time. Example YouTube vid here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeS0fh8xUVA  He does videos on extracting tables and looping files in a folder. You should be able to see easily how to set up extract tables from Excel workbook content.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you so much for pointing me that way ... I will certainly check them out ...